# How to Assign the String Array value to Collection or how to compare Array and LIst value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I have input of 1,2,3,4 that I will pass to a web service that will return valid ids only.

For example, the list [1,4] is valid, meaning it returns 1 and 4. i need 1 and 4 as valid list and 2 and 3 as invalid list.

I got the valid list from the web service `ValidList`. The question is, how to get the invalid list.

```
public ActionResult MethodName(Class LookUp)
{

  int totalRecords;

  Collection<Class> ValidList = new Collection<Class>();
  Collection<Class> invalidList = new Collection<Class>();

  string[] arrId = LookUp.SearchKey.Split(',');

  if (LookUp.SearchKey != "")
  {
    ValidList = Helpers.ProcessException<Collection<Class>>(() => WebserviceMethodName(LookUp));
  }

  totalRecords = ValidList.Count;

  // I  Tried This but it wont works
   //invalidList = lookUpList.Select(i => new { ID = i.ID }).Any(i => arrId);

  // I want Valid and Invalid List 

  return Json(lookUpList);                        
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something obvious but where is lookUpList?

Comment: You need to simplify your question and remove any trivial, just focus on what you stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try this
invalidList = lookUpList.Except(arrId.ToList()).

Comment: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Common.Models.Activity.Class>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'

Comment: i am getting above error while using ur code, i have collection , Array and Linq that is the problem